# Magento 2 Custom system config value not showing in custom email template

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, email-templates, system.xml

Able to get values of store phone number but not able to get custom config values(even it is working fine in root file when get custom config value)
How to get value for this  - {{config path="custom_finance/general/finance_text"}} ?

custom.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.frontend_name}} @-->
<!--@vars {

"var order_data.customer_name":"Customer Name"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
<tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>
            <p>Finance1</p>
            <p><strong>{{trans "Store Contact Number"}}</strong></p> 
            <p>{{config path="general/store_information/phone"}}</p> //it is working fine
            <p><strong>{{trans "Store Fianance Number"}}</strong></p>
            <p>{{config path="custom_finance/general/finance_text"}}</p> //not working

</td></tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="Xyz" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>XYZ</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="custom_finance" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Finance</label>
            <tab>Xyz</tab>
            <resource>Xyz_Custom::xyz_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="finance_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will show on email finance</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to add system config variables to email templates it is not enough that they are defined in system.xml and added to core_config_data.

You must also make them appear in the list of variables that appear when you click

Insert Variable…

In the email templates:

[image]

To do this you have to define a config path in your di.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configPaths" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_finance/general" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="custom_finance/general/finance_text" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

It will then appear in the variable list and you can use it in your email templates:

[image]

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I am able to show custom variable values in an email but I want to get from values using system config value

Comment: This is from system config. Read it carefully....

Comment: To be able to read a value from system config you have to add a node to configPaths in your di.xml, you can just not read any system value into your email templates. You have to first declare it as described above.

Comment: i add above code in di.xml but the variable not showing

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you check if you get it to display in Magento admin when you add variables to your emails?

Comment: Actually i am getting system config valuse in controllers,helpers and then try your code to convert in variable so it is not showing in variable like your showing above image

Comment: https://github.com/kristoffer124/email-config/tree/main/StackExchange There you have the code, put it it in app/code. run bin/magento module:enable StackExchange_EmailConfig && bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: In newer versions of Magento, the type in the di.xml needs to be `Magento\Variable\Model\Config\Structure\AvailableVariables` instead of `Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables`.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check **core_config_data** table has store value or not

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE "custom_finance%";
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: i am able to get values in other files like controllers helpers etc.. but this values is not coming in email templates